# Can't recreate deleted SSAS database

Tags: ssas, xmla

I didn't like the DatabaseID of my SSAS database, so I decide to delete/create it.

I generated a create script, and then a delete script.   I changed the ID in the create script to the one I want.

I ran the delete script.  It ran successfully.   Refreshed and verified the database has been deleted.

Now when I run the create script, I get:

"Either the user [MyUserName] does not have access to the [MyDatabaseName] database, or the database does not exist."

Well, no &*^% it doesn't exist, I'm trying to create it.

Googling hasn't yielded any results so far.   Any ideas?   Do I need to do some additional clean-up somewhere before I can recreate the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The create script is still "pointing at" the old cube. Close that query window and create a new one.

Comment: Well it turned out that trying the same script again with a new SSMS window did the trick, but I'd love an explanation of how the script is "pointing at" the old cube.  That doesn't happen with sql scripts like DROP/CREATE table.